# Page will refresh instead of redirecting

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML file that looks like the following:

```
<form onSubmit="getSearchResults()">
  <input id="search-query" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button onclick="getSearchResults()"></button>
</form>

<script type=text/javascript>
  var searchURL = "{% url 'search' %}" // I'm using Django, and this gets me the correct URL

  function getSearchResults(){
    var searchQuery = document.getElementById('search-query').value;
    if (searchQuery.length > 0)
        self.location.href = searchURL + '?' + searchQuery;
    else
        self.location.href = searchURL;
    return false;
  }

</script>
```

The idea is that every time I submit the form or click on the button, I want the page to be redirected to a different URL.

Right now, on either form submit or button click, the page just reloads. I looked at my console in Firefox and it says:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:8000/search
Navigated to http://localhost:8000/
```

So I know that my URL is correct and my code works somewhat because I am being navigated to the correct place, but then I'm being navigated to the original page I was on.

I have also tried:

```
window.location.href
location.href
```

Comment: Note that `<formonSubmit>` is invalid HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the button is in a form, it submits the form. Try adding `e.preventDefault()` inside the handler:

```
function getSearchResults(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var searchQuery = document.getElementById('search-query').value;
  if (searchQuery.length > 0)
    self.location.href = searchURL + '?' + searchQuery;
  else
    self.location.href = searchURL;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form onsubmit="return getSearchResults()">
```

Note `return`. This tells the `onsubmit` function to return what `getSearchResults()` returns. Otherwise `return false;` doesn't do anything.

Other approaches like `e.preventDefault()` work too.

Answer (score 1):

Page submits due to default type of the button.

```
<button type="button" ...
```

or

```
<button onclick="return getSearchResults()"></button>
```

Comment: The issue is not that it submits. It's that it reloads after submitting.